# Problem with adding new object to data base

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Hi i have an error when i trying add object to database. Error message is:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

My adding methods:

```
public void AddProduct(string category, FormCollection formCollection, HttpPostedFileBase image)   //Dodaje nowy produkt do bazy.
    {
        var product = GetNewProduct(category);
        var EfContext = GetEfContext(category);
        foreach(var property in product.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if(property.Name != "ImageData" && property.Name != "ImageMimeType")
            {
                var NewValue = Convert.ChangeType(formCollection[property.Name], property.PropertyType);
                property.SetValue(product, NewValue);
            }
            else 
            {
                if (property.Name == "ImageData")
                {
                    property.SetValue(product, new byte[image.ContentLength]);
                }
                if(property.Name == "ImageMimeType")
                {
                    property.SetValue(product, image.ContentType);
                }
                if(product.GetType().GetProperty("ImageData").GetValue(product) != null && product.GetType().GetProperty("ImageMimeType").GetValue(product) != null)
                {
                    image.InputStream.Read((byte[])product.GetType().GetProperty("ImageData").GetValue(product), 0, image.ContentLength);
                }
            }
        }
        EfContext.GetType().GetMethod("AddProduct").Invoke(EfContext, new object[] { product });
    }
```

And

```
public void AddProduct(GPU product)
    {
        product.Product_ID = productContext.items.Count() != 0 ? productContext.items.OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductID).Select(x => x.ProductID).FirstOrDefault() + 1 : 1;

        context.GPUs.Add(product);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Check that rowversion is not null.

Comment: How can I check it?